# Optimize select query (inner select + group)

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-optimization

My current version is :

```
SELECT     DT, AVG(DP_H2O) AS Tx,
           (SELECT    AVG(Abs_P) / 1000000 AS expr1
           FROM       dbo.BACS_MinuteFlow_1
           WHERE      (DT =
                                     (SELECT     MAX(DT) AS Expr1
                                       FROM      dbo.BACS_MinuteFlow_1
                                       WHERE     DT <= dbo.BACS_KongPrima.DT ))
          GROUP BY DT) AS Px
  FROM    dbo.BACS_KongPrima
  GROUP BY DT
```

but it works very slow.

basically in inner select I'm selecting maximum near time to my time, then group by this nearest time.

Is there possible optimizations ? Maybe I can join it somehow , but the trouble I'm not sure how to group by this nearest date.

Thank you

Comment: Have you added any indexes to BACS_MinuteFlow_1?  If you are looking to speed up the inner query, it might be worth adding an index on the DT column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to rearrange it to use the code below using a cross apply. Am not sure if this will improve performance but generally I try to avoid at all costs using a query on a specific column and SQL Server is pretty good at optimising the Apply statement.

```
WITH  Bacs_MinuteFlow_1  (Abs_P ,DT ) AS
(SELECT 5.3,'2011/10/10'
    UNION SELECT 6.2,'2011/10/10'
    UNION SELECT 7.8,'2011/10/10'
    UNION SELECT 5.0,'2011/03/10'
    UNION SELECT 4.3,'2011/03/10'),
BACS_KongPrima (DP_H2O ,DT)AS
(SELECT 2.3,'2011/10/15'
    UNION SELECT 2.6,'2011/10/15'
    UNION SELECT 10.2,'2011/03/15')

SELECT DT, AVG(DP_H2O) AS Tx,
       a.Px

FROM    BACS_KongPrima
CROSS APPLY  
(
SELECT AVG(Abs_P) / 1000000 AS Px 
FROM BACS_MinuteFlow_1 
WHERE DT =
    (SELECT     MAX(DT) AS maxdt 
     FROM      BACS_MinuteFlow_1
     WHERE     DT <= BACS_KongPrima.DT
    )
) a
GROUP BY DT,a.Px
```

Cheers